# Run time 13 Error when trying to store range from external workbook

Tags: excel, range, runtime-error, vba

Working on a macro to copy some data from another workbook and paste it on a sheet in the workbook with the macro.  I'm using this function which I adapted from another thread here to get the file path to the external workbook:

```
    Public Function RetrieveFileName() As String

    'Show the open dialog and pass the selected file name to the String variable "sFileName"
    RetrieveFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename

    'They have cancelled.
    If RetrieveFileName = "False" Then
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

It works and I'm able to get workbook to open, but when I try to store a range from the external workbook (last line in the snippet below), vba throws Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch.

```
Sub CreateSystemExtracts()
Dim thisRow As Long, wbkCheck As Long
Dim countryFilter As String, systemFilter As String
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceHeaders As Range

'Ask user where source data sits
Set sourceBook = Workbooks.Open(RetrieveFileName())

'Make sure they provided a source
If sourceBook Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "You must select a source file to continue, macro halted."
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check if number of rows in the selected file matches what we expect
sourceHeaders = Workbooks(sourceBook).Worksheets(Sheet1).Range("A2:X2")
```

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong?  I think it has something to do with the way I'm declaring the range on the last line, but I've tried a bunch of different methods and all give run time error 13.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When assigning object variables you need to use `Set`

```
'Check if number of rows in the selected file matches what we expect 
Set sourceHeaders = Workbooks(sourceBook).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:X2")
```

Comment: Thanks Tim - just tried that and its still throwing a run time error.  However I was able to make it work by iterating through all the different types of range references I could think of.  The one that finally worked was: Set sourceHeaders = sourceBook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:X2") - Any idea why this was the correct syntax?

Comment: See update- if `Sheet1` is not a variable name then it should be in quotes. Whether you use that or `Sheets(1)` would depend on how much you know about the structure of the workbooks being opened...